Get multiple messages from Service Broker queue
I have the following code:
WAITFOR(
    RECEIVE TOP (100)                   
        message_type_name,
        CAST(message_body AS XML),                  
        conversation_handle
    FROM MyDemoQueue
    INTO @ReceiveTable
), TIMEOUT 10000;

But I only get one entry even though there are 10 in the queue. I saw a lot of posts about this and I know that this is related to conversation groups and I should put the messages into one conversation group.
Service Broker only receiving one message at a time

All messages that are returned by a RECEIVE statement belong the same conversation group

But I can't find any code examples on how exactly I should implement this. Only theory. I can't even find it in the official documentation. Should this be on the sender's or the receiver's side? If anyone has ever done this before, please share code examples.
Here is how I send messages:
DECLARE @Handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @MessageBody XML = '<test>hello</test>'

BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @Handle 
    FROM SERVICE [SourceService]
    TO SERVICE 'TargetService'
    ON CONTRACT [TestContract]
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

SEND ON CONVERSATION @Handle
MESSAGE TYPE [TestMessage](@MessageBody);

And I do it several times from different places/batches. Also the following request returns multiple records:
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), message_body) AS Message
FROM MyDemoQueue


What does select * from MyDemoQueue returns? do you have different conversation groups? and do you really have 10 messages

@siggemannen it returns multiple records. But they have different conversation_handle and conversation_group_id. And i'm trying to find a way to put them into one group, so i can read all of them at once

Btw, why do you need to read them all at once? That's not really a nature of the messages

@siggemannen for example, I have a service that does some updates with users. This service reads a message from a queue, and the message contains user IDs. For example, the first message may contain IDs 1,2,3 and the second message may contain IDs 3,4,5. I want to combine these IDs into one list 1,2,3,4,5 and send it to my Stored Procedure for processing. If I read them one by one, I call my SP twice instead of once and i will send ID 3 to my SP twice instead of once. So this is some kind of performance optimization

Ok, but nothing stops you from reading the messages in a while-loop? something like: while 1 = 1 begin waitfor (...) if @@rowcount = 0 break  end and then do your thing with the @temp-variable

Messages are batched into conversation groups on send.  If the sender sends each message in a different conversation, you must receive them one-at-a-time.
Conversations can be long-lived and you can reuse existing conversations across multiple SENDs, and when you do you get in-order delivery and batch receives on the target service.
